# Why implement IEqualityComparer<T> in a separate class

Tags: c#, linq, compare

When I was looking up the generic `IEqualityComparer` interface on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) I noticed the interface was implemented in a separate 'comparer' class, opposed to `IEquatable<T>` which is implemented in the class itself. When I searched for some more examples, every single one was using a separate class and that got me wondering: **why not implement it on the class itself?**

I can imagine overriding `object.Equals` and `object.GetHashCode` isn't considered good practice because it's used in a lot of different situations, but even msdn says (emphasis mine):

> This interface allows the implementation of customized equality comparison for **collections**.

so its uses are pretty much limited to Linq. There's only 2 reasons I can think of why to define a separate comparer class:

1. Different methods on a collection of the class require a different comparer.
2. The class is big and instantiating another object of it isn't desired (although if that's really the issue, why isn't having a whole collection of it not bad?).

**So my question is:**

Is there any particular reason that I overlooked which causes everyone to define another comparerclass just for comparing instead of just implementing the interface on the class itself (which would not be worse in my opinion to say the least)?

A small example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test t1 = new Test { id = 1, date = default(DateTime) };
    Test t2 = new Test { id = 1, date = default(DateTime) };
    Test t3 = new Test { id = 0, date = default(DateTime) };
    List<Test> testList = new List<Test>{ t1, t2, t3 };

    //Same result
    int distinctCountClass = testList.Distinct(new Test()).Count();
    int distinctCountComparerClass = testList.Distinct(new TestComparer()).Count();
}

public partial class Test
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}

public partial class Test : IEqualityComparer<Test>
{
    public bool Equals(Test x, Test y) { return x.id == y.id && x.date == y.date; }
    public int GetHashCode(Test obj) { return obj.id.GetHashCode(); }
}

public class TestComparer : IEqualityComparer<Test>
{
    public bool Equals(Test x, Test y) { return x.id == y.id && x.date == y.date; }
    public int GetHashCode(Test obj) { return obj.id.GetHashCode(); }
}
```

Comment: You are correct with the first and partially correct with the second reason. The class is "big" but it's nothing to do with instantiating and instead has to do with "your class does too much". A class that represents a certain set of data or behavior is something vastly different than a class that compares two classes that do that.

Comment: It seems very unnatural to use an instance of an object to compare two other instances of the same type... If you want to implement a comparison operator for a type within that type, you should implement `IEquatable<T>`

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes but many linq methods need an instance of `IEqualityComparer<T>`, Distinct, Groupby etc. If I just implement `IEquatable<T>` those methods won't work

Comment: If you want to use `IEqualityComparer<T>` for a type `T` then implement `IEquatable<T>` for that type and use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` which will automatically use the implementation of  `IEqualityComparer<T>` that you wrote for `T`.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks :)

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but I also want to point out that when implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` OR `IEquatable<T>`, you should generally only use immutable properties in the comparison. Reason being, if they're mutable and you put the object into a collection like a HashSet and then mutate one of those properties, nasty things are likely to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why not implement it on the class itself?

Because it makes no sense. The whole purpose of the `IEqualityComparer<T>` is to be implemented outside the type `T` because it targets the *"reason 1"* from your post.

If you want the class itself to implement the equality logic, then you are expected to implement `IEquatable<T>` which is provided specifically for such scenario, and `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` will provide the necessary bridge to your implementation anytime `IEqualityComparer<T>` is needed and not specified explicitly.

Since the class can provide only one hardcoded logic without any dynamic behavior and/or options, it's considered to be the **default** equality logic, hence the name of the static `EqualityProvider<T>` property providing access to it.

Comment: I didn't realize `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` used `IEquatable<T>`, that is indeed the best solution for me as Matthew pointed out in the comments :)

Comment: Well, I haven't read his comments, but now I have, so looks like I'm just confirming it :)

Comment: Accepting this as it's the approach I'm going to use

Answer (score 4):

`IComparer<T>` as well as `IEqualityComparer<T>` work with *two* instances of T so they have no need to be implemented as a part of `T` class; however, implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` within the `T` is a good practice, the scheme can be

```
  public partial class Test {
    private class TestComparer : IEqualityComparer<Test> {
      public bool Equals(Test x, Test y) { 
        return x.id == y.id && x.date == y.date; 
      }

      public int GetHashCode(Test obj) { 
        return obj.id.GetHashCode(); 
      }
    }

    // Please, note "static"
    public static IEqualityComparer<Test> MyTestComparer {get;} = new TestComparer();

    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    ...
  }
```

In this case you just use the comparer you want:

```
int distinctCountComparerClass = testList.Distinct(Test.MyTestComparer).Count();
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of defining it inside the class, I like that. I didn't like the separate class because I don't like creating tons of helper classes that don't contribute much

Comment: In my opinion you should just implement `IEquatable<T>` for the class and let consumers use  `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` if they want a comparer for that class.

Comment: @Alexander Derck: when class (`Test`) is simple enough than `TestComparer` and other comparers within the `Test` look OK; when `Test` is complex, combining all the comparers into special `public static class TestComparer` is a better approach (see `String` and `StringComparer` classes)

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, this way you can use different ways of comparing objects from the same class depending on the context.

It's basically inversion of control: it is not for the class itself to decide how another class might want to compare its instances.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` rather than `IEquatable<T>`, because when a class implements the `IEquatable<T>` interface, it enters a contract in which it states "I know how to compare two instances of type `T` or any type derived from `T` for equality". However if that class is derived, it is very unlikely that the base class will know how to make a meaningful comparison. Therefore, that implicit contract is now broken.

Alternatively, the class whose instances we want to be `comparable`, could be made `sealed`, but for the reasons already stated in this conversation thread, the other approach is much more elegant.